# activerecord-postgis-adapter v2 do not create separate schema in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

I'm updating Rails 3.2 project with activerecord-postgis-adapter (0.6.5) to Rails 4.0 (ar-postgis-adapter 2.2.1).

When I try to create test db via `rake db:create` created db has only one `public` schema with `spatial_ref_sys` table and PostGIS functions.

When I try to clone development db to test I have errors on tables with postgis columns: `type "postgis.geography" does not exist`.

From [source code](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/blob/2.0-stable/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter/postgis_database_tasks.rb#L113) I discovered that gem accepts new param `postgis_schema` from connection configuration (this param do not specified in readme). In early versions separate schema name was extracted from `schema_search_path`. I specified it but nothing was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in this version of activerecord-postgis-adapter because of SQL-schema. To clone db correctly you need to dump and load non-sql schema:

```
rake db:schema:dump
rake db:test:load_schema
```

Or add this task:

```
Rake::Task["db:test:clone"].clear

namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :clone => [:environment] do
      puts 'Dumping development schema...'
      Rake::Task['db:schema:dump'].invoke

      puts 'Loading development schema into test database...'
      Rake::Task['db:test:load_schema'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the the "issue in this version of activerecord-postgis-adapter"? I am experiencing a similar problem with the postgis schema not being pouplated correctly after a dump.